# Find the real domain of a link to a my page, when called from an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

Technical question.

Is it possible to know the real domain from which a site was referred from, when it is referred via an iframe?

Simply put, we have a site, someone created an iframe code and is using it to refer to our site. The reason he used an iframe is to hide the real domain from which the referral is taking place.
Is there a way for us to find it the real domain on which the iframe was placed.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for misunderstanding your question.

It is **impossible** to find where others put a iframe pointing to your server. Instead, you can **view logs** on your web server to see who is **connecting**, **spamming** your server.

To view logs on your server, in **Apache Web Servers**, they are probably stored in:

> /var/log/apache2/error.log

More details at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/14763/where-are-the-apache-and-php-log-files

To view logs on a **web hosting**, you probably have to see their documentation or tutorials. Or contacting them by customer support.

I hope my answer can solve your problem.

Comment: Where exactly should this code be placed. just you be clear I have no access to the iframe itself, it does not belong to me and I do not know where it is placed. What I know is that my site is called from that Iframe which is placed on sites which I do not want to be referred from.

Comment: @Dan. G Sorry for misunderstanding your question. The question is now edited.

Comment: Anthony, thank you for your detailed responce. In the logs I will see the URL of the iframe (which does not belong to me), but not the url of the parent site on which they placed the iframe. It is cruicial for me to know where the iframe was placed, the parent url. I know that if I would have been able to inject a js into that iframe in some cases i could have requested the parent url, but that is not the case, I only get the information that is passed along with the click on the links that points to my site that was placed within the iframe that does not belong to me - sorry for being looong

Comment: @Dan.G I am sorry that I couldn't help you with the question.